# How to split a list into chucks of different sizes specified by another list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have an array I am trying to split into chunks of different sizes.

In the example below, `loopN` is are the chuck sizes. I have tried all sorts of ways to iterate through `loopN`, however can't figure it out. `list` is the array I am trying to split into chunks.

```
loopN = [2,3,1]
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

for i in range(0, len(list), loopN):
    chunks.append(list[i:i+loopN])
```

The output I was looking for was `[[1,2],[3,4,5],[6]]`.

How do I split the array into chucks of different sizes?

Comment: Please do not use keywords such as `list` for variable names.

Comment: what do you expect `i + loopN` to do? `i` is a number, `loopN` is a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to loop over the `loopN` list, not `list`. Then you can get the appropriate slice of the list.

I've renamed `list` to `l` below, to avoid using a built-in keyword.

```
i = 0
chunks = []
loopN = [2,3,1]
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

for chunksize in loopN:
    chunks.append(l[i:i+chunksize])
    i += chunksize
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to take slices of `l` according to the elements in `loopN`:

```
from itertools import islice

loopN = [2,3,1]
l = iter([1,2,3,4,5,6])

[list(islice(l, i)) for i in loopN]
# [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6]]
```

---

If you want to stick to list methods, following your approach, there are a few things that are wrong already spotted by @barmar. Note that the slice `i:i+loopN` doesn't really make sense. You cannot add an integer and a list.

You need to iterate over the values that will be used to slice `l`, so over `loopN`. Also you don't need ranges, just directly iterate over `loopN`, which *is* an iterable too, and keep track over the previous values you've iterated over, adding them on each iteration to move the slices forward.